# How can I display a message if a value already exists in database?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2013

I am currently writing my first .Net & C# application with Visual Studio, and have a need to write generated values to MySQL from the application. 
At present, I can write values fine - but I need to be able to check to see if a value exists and display that line if it does exist, otherwise insert new line to table. My connection string is defined at the top of the form.

I have the following defined already, and it writes to the database successfully if no duplicate values exist in the LicenseKey column. If a duplicate exists, it throws an unhandled exception.

```cs
private void SaveDetails()
{
    // MySQL 'insert' command
    string InsertNewLicense = "insert into BCOM.LicenseDetails(LicenseeName,ComputerName,ContactName,ContactEmail,LicenseKey,CreationDate) values('" +this.textBoxLicenseeName.Text+ "','" +this.textBoxComputerName.Text+ "','" +this.textBoxContactName.Text+ "','" +this.textBoxContactEmail.Text+ "','" +this.textBoxLicenseKey.Text+ "','" +this.textBoxCreationDate.Text+ "');";
    //MySQL instance details
    MySqlConnection InsertLicenseDetails = new MySqlConnection(LicenseDatabaseConnection);
    //MySQL command execution
    MySqlCommand InsertCommand = new MySqlCommand(InsertNewLicense, InsertLicenseDetails);
    // Handles command outputs.
    MySqlDataReader InsertReader;
    //Opens connection to run query on database
    InsertLicenseDetails.Open();
    // Here our query will be executed and data saved into the database.
    MessageBox.Show("License Details Saved. Please ensure you have emailed the license to the customer.");
    while (InsertReader.Read())
    {

    }
    InsertLicenseDetails.Close();
}
```

What I want to happen is for a check to be run on the LicenseKey column to see if the value exists, before different actions are taken.
If the value does not exist, I would like to insert the new line to the table (like my existing command does).

If, however, the value *does* exist, I would like to pop up a form showing the values from the line that the duplicate appears in as a form.

Where would I put in an event handler to read MySQLException values? What exception would I have to respond to for a duplicate value or no database response?

Comment: You wouldn't want to use exceptions as flow control... You should first check if the value exists and then depending on the result choose what to do. So write a method (i.e. IsLicenseKeyInDatabase), call it and then decide if you want to save or display an error message.

Comment: So I would have to do something like check if the value exists, and if it does then display otherwise run the insert command?

Comment: That is exactly what you should do...

Comment: I must also warn you though. You have a massive security problem in your code. There is a great, and i mean GREAT, risk for SQL injection. You should use parameterized queries instead.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback on the injection dangers. I have changed to a parameterized query for the insert statement, and will use the same style for future queries I write in the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the queries for a while I decided to try a different tack - instead of using a direct check if it's there, I opted to use a count(*) query. When I click the save button on the form, the buttonClick_event calls SaveDetails(), which runs the following:

```
    private void SaveDetails()
    {
        string InsertNewLicense = "INSERT into BCOM.LicenseDetails(LicenseeName,ComputerName,ContactName,ContactEmail,LicenseKey,CreationDate) values(@LicenseeName, @ComputerName, @ContactName, @ContactEmail, @LicenseKey, @CreationDate)";
        string LicenseExistence = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM BCOM.LicenseDetails WHERE LicenseKey LIKE @LicenseKey";

        MySqlConnection LicenseDetails = new MySqlConnection(LicenseDatabaseConnection);

        MySqlCommand InsertCommand = new MySqlCommand(InsertNewLicense, LicenseDetails);
        InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LicenseeName", this.textBoxLicenseeName.Text);
        InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ComputerName", this.textBoxComputerName.Text);
        InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactName", this.textBoxContactName.Text);
        InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactEmail", this.textBoxContactEmail.Text);
        InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LicenseKey", this.textBoxLicenseKey.Text);
        InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreationDate", this.textBoxCreationDate.Text);

        MySqlCommand QueryCommand = new MySqlCommand(LicenseExistence, LicenseDetails);
        QueryCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LicenseKey", this.textBoxLicenseKey.Text);

        MySqlDataReader InsertReader;

        LicenseDetails.Open();
        if ((int)(long)QueryCommand.ExecuteScalar() >0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("This license already exists in the database.");
        }
        else
        {
            InsertReader = InsertCommand.ExecuteReader();
            MessageBox.Show("License Details Saved. Please ensure you have emailed the license to the customer.");
            while (InsertReader.Read())
            {

            }
        }
        LicenseDetails.Close();
```

So, if the query against the license keys returns with any results at all (more than 0 rows returned), a messagebox pops up showing that the key already exists. If the resultant number of rows is 0, the insert command gets run.

This was figured out with a look through MySQL command notes, testing with phpMyAdmin, matching against existing projects online, and support from the following:
The SELECT query was figured out with great support from @Seige.
The query was parameterized with help from [Seige](https://stackoverflow.com/users/929834/seige), following on from the advice of [Sani Huttunen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26742/sani-huttunen). Many thanks to them both.
Changing to the count method was done on the advice of a fellow coder in another community online - a good friend and brilliant coder.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what the others have said in their comments, you could change the SQL Query to do the check instead of having 2.

```
IF(SELECT ... WHERE A = B)
     RETURN THAT THE VALUE ALREADY EXISTS    
ELSE 
     INSERT NEW VALUE
```

Also there was a good comment about SQL Injection and parameterized queries. The query string should look a bit more like

```
INSERT into BCOM.LicenseDetails(LicenseeName,ComputerName,ContactName,ContactEmail,LicenseKey,CreationDate) values(@LicenseeName, @ComputerName, @ContactName ...);
```

and your SqlCommand be parameterized

```
InsertCommand.Paramaters.AddWithValue("@LicenseeName", this.textBoxLicenseeName.Text);
InsertCommand.Paramaters.AddWithValue("@ComputerName", this.textBoxComputerName.Text);
...
```

That should be a good start to get you going.

Comment: Thanks for the info on how to parameterize my query - I hadn't considered that a direct string would be so directly vulnerable.
With the select query - would that be something like the following:

        "SELECT * FROM `LicenseDetails` WHERE `LicenseKey` LIKE '@LicenseKey"'

Comment: You don't need to put the quotes around the @Variables in the query. Just in the Paramaters.AddWithValue() which does everything for you like that. But otherwise that's right.

Comment: So how would I merge the two commands into one IfTTT string?
I have the two strings at present, looking like this:

`string InsertNewLicense = "INSERT into BCOM.LicenseDetails(LicenseeName,ComputerName,ContactName,ContactEmail,LicenseKey,CreationDate) values(@LicenseeName, @ComputerName, @ContactName, @ContactEmail, @LicenseKey, @CreationDate)";`
Along with:

`string LicenseExistence = "SELECT * FROM BCOM.LicenseDetails WHERE LicenseKey LIKE @LicenseKey";`
My parameters are all defined and working with the first string. How would I convert that to a proper single command?

Comment: Your SqlCommand will execute the command text like it would if you were using Management Studio, you can put the 2 statements together, separated by a SemiColon ' ; '. You just have to be careful that if you have 2 parameters with the same name, they are the same data. If you have more than one return set, then you can move to the next one with InsertReader.Next();